# Springboot JPA batching for bulk updates

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I built an application to update 10000 records. But the concern is performance and efficiency as it is a workaround for a production issue. I want do the update batch wise but the code that implemented seems not to be working. I cannot change the entity related configs as the solution is already deployed in production and this is a workaround. The following is the code in the repo.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE orders o SET o.status = 'OK', o.modified_date_time = :modifiedDateTime WHERE o.order_id IN :idList", nativeQuery = true)
int updateDetails(@Param("modifiedDateTime") String modifiedDateTime, @Param("idList") List<String> idList);
```

Following is the method I'm calling in the service class.

```
List<String> manuallyUpdatedRecordsList = orderRepository.getManuallyUpdatedOrderList(dateTime, idList);
```

I tried to add the yaml configurations to see if the update is happening batch wise but there is only one hibernate update log. I would be expecting to see multiple update logs if the batch processing is happening.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 400
        order_updates: true
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with batch updates, if any you even have single transcations which is slow. There has been plenty of questions with answers been made on JPA on how to use that in batch processing scenarios, so I would suggest doing some research first.

Comment: You are executing one query. There is no batching involved.

Comment: I want to improve the code in a way that it would allow me to do batch updates. The initial thought process was to do batch updates using a for loop but saw the yaml configs in an article so at the moment looking to see whether there is a possibility to do the batch updates using configurations.